# DataGridviewLinkColumn Edit/Update

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am Implementing a Edit/Update functionality in c# datagridview desktop application. For the Update column i am using datagridviewlinkcolumn. when i click on "edit" link the text should be changed to "Update". I have tried and i did n't get any solution. 
I tried this ` DataGridViewLinkCell cell = (DataGridViewLinkCell)dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

```
            cell.Value = "Update";`
```

But it wont work

```
     private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int nCurrentRow = e.RowIndex;
        int nTranscriptGuidId = 0;

        if (-1 != nCurrentRow && dataGridView2.CurrentCell == dataGridView2.Rows[nCurrentRow].Cells["Edit"])
        {
            // dataGridView2.Rows[nCurrentRow].Cells[].
            DataGridViewLinkCell cell = (DataGridViewLinkCell)dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.Value = "Update";
            dataGridView2.Update();
            //dataGridView2.Referesh();
        }
```

Comment: Try calling the datagridView.Update() and datagridView.Referesh()

Comment: still not working

Comment: Please paste your xaml and xaml.cs code here to understand it better.

Comment: please check above code

Comment: Please help as soon as possible